# Reducing Timer Softirq and local interrupts

Tags: apic, softirq

I would like to know what exactly are the TIMER softirqs in */proc/softirqs* are doing, so I can reduce their frequency. I believe the local timer interrupts generated by the local APIC give rise to these TIMER softirqs.

So is changing the frequency of APIC the only way to reduce the number of TIMER softirqs generated? Is it possible that these TIMER softirqs of a particular CPU can be delegated to another CPU?